# C# json.net json string loop to place into class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json.net, stringify

Hey all I am in need of some help with trying to figure out how to go about looping through a returned JSON.stringify string to a POST in my asp.net mvc page.

My javascript:

```
var result = JSON.stringify(data);

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'saveUpdate',
  cache: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
      bomdata: result
  },
  success: function (response) {
      console.log('has been updated');
  },
  error: function (response) {
      console.log(response);
  }
});
```

And my ASP.net MVC Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public string saveUpdate(string bomdata)
{
    dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(bomdata);

    //Needing to add the loop here and place all data into my class
    //and continue until its at the end of the loop          

    resultsBack.Add("dback", "GOOD");
    resultsBack.Add("dhead", "Added BOM # " + bomdata.number);
    resultsBack.Add("dinfo", "BOM was updated successfully");
    resultsBack.Add("guid", bomdata.theGuid);

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultsBack, Formatting.Indented);
}
```

And the json string thats being posted:

```
[{
  "description": "1f43f",
  "environment": 2,
  "manufacturer": 3,
  "vendor": 5,
  "hardwarePartNumber": "v3rg",
  "hardwareModelNumber": "35hg33",
  "softwarePartNumber": "3f",
  "softwareVersion": "2f",
  "guid": ""
}, {
  "description": "674h",
  "environment": 5,
  "manufacturer": 1,
  "vendor": 33,
  "hardwarePartNumber": "54eth",
  "hardwareModelNumber": "5yh55",
  "softwarePartNumber": "32hnj4",
  "softwareVersion": "4.9",
  "guid": ""
}]
```

My class:

```
public class bValues
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int environment { get; set; }
    public int manufacturer { get; set; }
    public int vendor { get; set; }
    public string hardwarePartNumber { get; set; }
    etc...etc....
}
```

All I really need is to be able to loop through that json and place the data into my class, save it to my DB and then do it again with another loop depending on how much data is in there.

So, taken from the example above, I have 2 sets of json values coming back **[{ set1 },{ set2 }]**

I want to place **each** set into my class:

```
Dictionary<string, string> _tmpParms = new Dictionary<string, string>();
StringBuilder buildTblVal = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder buildTblName = new StringBuilder();

//Start loop....
HELPer.bomLineValues bomdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HELPer.bomLineValues>(bomdata);

//Now loop through that set and format it like
//blah1: something1, blah2: something2, blah3: something3, etc..
foreach (var prop in bomdata.GetType().GetProperties())
{
   if (prop.PropertyType.Name == "Int32")
   {
      buildTblVal.Append(prop.Name + ": " + prop.GetValue(bomdata) + ",");
   }
   else
   {
      buildTblVal.Append(prop.Name + ": " + "'" + prop.GetValue(bomdata) + "',");
   }
}

//Remove trailing comma
buildTblVal.Length = buildTblVal.Length - 1;
buildTblName.Length = buildTblName.Length - 1;

//Now save to the DB
_tmpParms.Add("1", buildTblName.ToString());
_tmpParms.Add("2", buildTblVal.ToString());            
SQLHelper.callSQLSP("spUpdateBom", _tmpParms, "", false);

//Now loop back and get the next set of data to do the same with
```

Any help would be great!!

Comment: Why are you using `dynamic` when you have a POCO class that represents the data?

Comment: I think you could do that `var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<bValues>>(bomdata);`

Comment: @mmushtaq when i do that i get **Error CS1056 Unexpected character '​'**

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deserializing to the POCO class you already created?

```
bValues[] results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bValues[]>(bomdata);
```

Then itterate over results:

```
foreach (bValues item in results )
{
    //do something with item.description 
    //do something with item.vendor
    //etc
}
```

Comment: Nice maccettura but I am looking to ultimately add those values to my class and just save that data and loop again and do the same thing over again.

Comment: What class are you trying to add the values to?

Comment: Updated my OP so that, hopefully, it will make more since.

Comment: With my solution your data is **already in your class**.  `results` will be an array of `bValues` objects, 1 object for every group of your json.

Comment: Correct but how do i loop with that since it has more than one set of values?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are asking.  According to your post you want to " loop through that json and place the data into my class".  Your json example is an array of objects, thats why it deserializes to an array of objects.  You can iterate through the array and save each object to your database.  Are you asking how to loop through each property of your class?

Comment: Ok let me try to revise the OP so it makes more since.

Comment: Alright, see if my OP makes better sence to you now